# Only show rows where mysql subquery returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a receipts table, to pull order numbers from a database who's first transaction falls within a certain time range. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT id, order_number, 
(
  SELECT id FROM receipts 
  WHERE received < r.received AND order_number = r.order_number 
  LIMIT 1
) priorPayment 
FROM receipts r 
WHERE received > 1416384000 AND received < 1416470399 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This works fine except I want to filter out anything that has a priorPayment returned (so only show where this subquery returns null) right now it returns everything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use a subquery for this or a `having` clause, I would recommend simply using a `left join`

```
SELECT r.id, r.order_number
FROM receipts r LEFT JOIN
     receipts r2
     ON r2.received < r.received and r2.order_number = r.order_number
WHERE r.received > 1416384000 AND r.received < 1416470399 AND
      r2.order_number is NULL
ORDER BY r.id DESC;
```

Comment: Just to clarify on this, since I am joining the table to itself I must specify which one I'm querying from in the SELECT clause otherwise it throws an ambiguous column error, otherwise this works and keeps it simple, thanks!

Comment: @Mazzy . . . You are correct.  All the columns should be qualified (a good practice anyway).

Answer (score 1):

another way is just bring the `subquery` from `select` into `where` clause:

```
SELECT id, order_number, null as priorPayment 
FROM receipts r 
WHERE received > 1416384000 AND received < 1416470399 
and (
  SELECT id FROM receipts 
  WHERE received < r.received AND order_number = r.order_number 
  LIMIT 1
) is null
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks this worked too, to clarify though I did not actually need to return the third column as null, I was just doing this to have a visual on my query to make sure it was doing the right thing, thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance I would recommand to keep the sub-query (which selects only the 3 columns you need) and combine it, with the LEFT JOIN and the IS NULL condition to get the expected result:

```
SELECT r.id, r.order_number
FROM receipts r 
left join (
SELECT id, received, order_number FROM receipts 
) priorPayment
ON priorPayment.received < r.received 
AND priorPayment.order_number = r.order_number
WHERE r.received > 1416384000 
AND r.received < 1416470399 
AND r.priorPayment.id is null
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a common way to write that:

```
SELECT r.id, r.order_number
FROM receipts r
WHERE r.received > 1416384000 AND r.received < 1416470399  
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM receipts WHERE received < r.received AND order_number = r.order_number LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

Alternatively, you can use an anti-join in this case:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.order_number
FROM receipts r1
LEFT JOIN receipts r2
  ON r2.order_number = r1.order_number AND r2.received < r1.received
WHERE r1.received > 1416384000 AND r1.received < 1416470399
  AND r2.order_number is NULL
ORDER BY r1.id DESC
```